# MouseClick not registering on FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to click on "View Users" but for some reason it works with Chrome but not firefox.

```
//this clicks on the Admin tasks on the top. 
driver.findElement(By.id("x-auto-34")).click();
//moves mouse over user profile management under the drop down menu for admin task
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("UserProfileManagement"))).build().perform();
//finds user configuration and clicks.
    driver.findElement(By.id("ViewUsers")).click();
```

I tried this with xpath also but got the same issue only with firefox.[image]

When i run it, it doesnt get any noelement found exception or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me a lot when developing Selenium automation. Sometimes actions executed on a `WebElement` just fail to work. I use a Javascript workaround to execute clicks when the Selenium click method doesn't work:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ViewUsers"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```